# How can one get reference to the outer class from inner class not using outer class name?

Tags: java, android

Here is the sample code:

```
Class SomeClass extends Activity {
    public void someMethod() {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent service = new Intent(SomeClass.this, SomeOtherClass.class);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the code to not use `SomeClass` ( in `new Intent(SomeClass.this, ...)`)?
I want to place this sample in multiple classes and I do not want each time use different class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shorter method (suggested):**

Replacing `SomeClass.this` in your Intent with `getApplicationContext()` should do the trick.

**Method I use (a little more drawn out and probably not the best of the two):**

In each class, make a `private Context mContext;`
Then, in the `onCreate()` of each class, make `mContext = this;`
Finally, replace `SomeClass.this` in your Intent with `mContext`.

Comment: this answer is good, and provide good solution, but I want to mention that holding reference to context with mContext should done carefully. it can easy lead to memory leek.

Comment: Solution is acceptable... And it seems that I will use it, thanks... But is there a pure java way to access outer class without any private fields and calling any methods of superclass (`Activity` in this case)?

Comment: If you have multiple classes in which you are creating a field to store a reference to the context, getting the context statically might be a a prefered way:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android